# Why is my lm() model unaltered by addition of a random effect?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, lm

I have a dataset with repeated measures (each plantID is tested at 4 different ppm of CO2 - image below). I have tried analyzing the data with and without a random effect of plantID:

lm(CER ~ ppm, data = dataset) and

lm(CER ~ ppm + (1|plantID), data=dataset)

The output is identical in both cases. This even happens when I make up a "toy" example with a strong effect of plant ID, where I would really expect different results with and without the random effect.

Adding the random effect causes a "Coefficient not defined because of singularities" message. However, according to the cor() function, my two independent variables (plantID and ppm) are NOT correlated with each other, which is often given as the explanation for this error message. Is the structure of the data incorrect in some way..? Should I simply refrain from adding a random effect of plant ID to this model?

[image: Sample of dataset used: plantID, ppm, CER]

Comment: I apologise if my question is dumb, but are you sure that lm is the right function ? Or should you use this package to do that ? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf

Comment: could you show us the model summary in both cases?

Comment: Unrelated to your question but a good practice to follow: You include data with your question but only an image. This is actually not quite useful. The easiest way to provide data is probably to paste the output of `dput(<yourData>)` or `dput(head(<yourData>))`. [datapasta](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/index.html) is handy as well. You should also include the summary of the models (with `summary(fitted_model)`) as @frank suggests. Please don't leave out information you refer to in the question.

Comment: How many plants have you collected data from in your experiment?

Answer (score 8):

`lm` is a function for estimating fixed-effects regression only, it does not handle random effects. For random effects, you need to use libraries such as *nlme* or *lme4*.

What your code does is it translates `|` to logical or operation, because R allows for such operations in the formula. In mixed-effects models (when using the packages above), the operation is overloaded and has a special meaning. To convince yourself, look at the result of the code below:

```r
> model.matrix(lm(mpg ~ hp + (1|carb) + (0|am), data=mtcars))
                    (Intercept)  hp 1 | carbTRUE 0 | amTRUE
Mazda RX4                     1 110            1          1
Mazda RX4 Wag                 1 110            1          1
Datsun 710                    1  93            1          1
Hornet 4 Drive                1 110            1          0
Hornet Sportabout             1 175            1          0
Valiant                       1 105            1          0
Duster 360                    1 245            1          0
Merc 240D                     1  62            1          0
Merc 230                      1  95            1          0
Merc 280                      1 123            1          0
...
```

As you can see, `(1|carb)` produced a column of ones as `1 OR something` leads to all values being true (ones), `(0|am)` leads to `0 OR 1-or-0` leads to ones, and zeros depending on the second column, because the left-hand side is false (zero). You can also see a hint in the column names `1 | carbTRUE`.

It is a consequence of the fact that R allows for great flexibility when writing the code, here it backfires leading to unexpected behavior for someone familiar with mixed-effects formulas.

The constant column would not change anything about linear regression results.

Comment: Great explanation! Your first two lines would have been a complete answer, but the rest wonderfully explains what happens under the hood in R. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds good but doesn't explain the reference to a "Coefficient not defined because of singularities" message. It's the `glm` function which throws it. So on top of the issue you've described, the OP may have copy-pasted her code wrong and may be confused between generalized linear models and mixed effects models.

Comment: @dipetkov what the error is irrelevant because the function is used incorrectly and the software is poorly designed allowing for this and not failing on wrong input with relevant error message.

Comment: Yes I know -- garbage in, garbage out. However, it addresses the actual question the OP asked.

Comment: @dipetkov I don't think a full debugging session is needed in here. It is obvious why it doesn't work, where exactly R fails here is irrelevant for the end user.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I appreciate the guidance. First time poster - I'll know how to do it better next time!!

Comment: @Arielle if it answers your question you can accept it (the “v” button) so people know it's solved.