# Identical intercept and random effect values in multinomial regression model in R

Tags: r, biostatistics, multinomial-logit, nnet

I have 6 animals whose behaviour I’m testing over multiple trials. It’s a pretty small dataset (max 15 observations per animal). Behaviour falls into multiple types. The same behaviour can occur multiple times per animal, and trial numbers vary per animal. This data is organised lengthwise, with one row per observation.

I’m interested to see if behavioural type is influenced by trial number, so I fitted a multinomial model in R with the `multinom` function in the `nnet` package. Formula: `Behaviour ~ Trial + (1 | AnimalID)`. The model works fine, no errors are reported, and the coefficients seemingly match patterns that I can observe in the dataset.

What I find very strange is that the random effects coefficients are exactly identical to the behavioural intercept coefficients. Same for the corresponding standard errors.
When I remove animal ID as a random effect from the model, the model fit (residuals and AIC) remain exactly the same. Both the intercept coefficients and their standard errors, however, are twice as large as in the prior model.
What is happening here?

Comment: Does `nnet::multinom` allow random effects?

Comment: @dipetkov I don't think so. What's odd is that this didn't give errors. I'm not sure what it did.

Comment: @PeterFlom This seems to be one of those questions with a bit of misdirection thrown in to check whether one is paying attention. It turns out that if `AnimalID` is numeric, then multinom treats the whole term `(1 | AnimalID)` as numeric also.

Comment: @dipetkov i'm pretty sure animal ID is a factor, actually. i've specified it as such prior to fitting the model (with `factor()`)and the random effect is listed as `1 | AnimalIDTRUE` in the model output tables.

Comment: Call [`model.matrix`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/model.matrix) on your fitted model.

Comment: @dipetkov the random effect = 1 for all rows of the matrix; i guess that's why the model coefficients end up the same as for the intercept(?)

Comment: As already pointed out, multinom doesn't interpret (1 | AnimalID) as a random effect. I recall a thread explaining this same issue & now I found it: [Why is my lm() model unaltered by addition of a random effect?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/582911/237901).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions about code are off topic here and this question might get closed, but, from what I can tell `multinom` in the `nnet` package does not fit repeated measures. Certainly the main help page for the `multinom` function doesn't mention that.

If you want to run a multinomial logistic with repeated measures you can use the `lme4` package, see this [old thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280423/is-it-currently-possible-to-run-a-multinomial-logistic-regression-with-random-su) (which is closed but has an answer) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76623653/mixed-effect-multinomial-logistic-regression-model-in-r-non-bayesian-approach) from Stack Overflow, which does not have an answer, but has some useful comments. Also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67607696/fitting-a-ordinal-logistic-mixed-effect-model?rq=2) which suggests using the `clmm` function from the `ordinal` package.